Hangfire Hangfire.Core.resources not found
When running a dotnet project that has a dependency on Hangfire, the following error is encountered
Could not load file or assembly 'Hangfire.Core.resources, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have installed Hangfire.Core but still same error occurs.

Can you extend your question with set up. Version of dotnet that you are using and version of hangfire ?
